# How should I partition my Ubuntu 10.10 install?

Tags: 10.10, partitioning, installation

I have about 12-15 GBs of disk space on which I am about to install Ubuntu 10.10.

I am considering following partitioning scheme:

14GB partition with 10GB root, 2GB swap (I have 4GB RAM) & 2GB home

People say to keep a partition /home, as it will have backup of my user setting and useful when i upgrade, is that correct?

Kindly guide me if this is okay, or suggest a different partitioning scheme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly partitioning will depend upon what you like to do with your system. However I am attempting to answer  assuming typical use.

Yes, keeping `/home` as a separate partition will help you to retain all personal data even when you do a wipe out re-install of OS with same version or higher version. (Such re-install  is recommended than upgrade). If you want further granular control you can create more partitions based on need.

Generally you will not have more than 2-4 GB of data (it can vary based on what you install, but if you use default logrotate to keep logs cleared and do not use system for ever growing data like databases)  in root if you are keeping only two partitions namely `/home` and `/root`.

This assumes all your personal files goes to `/home`. So probably keeping ~6 GB to root , at-least same size as of RAM as swap (only if you expect any possibility of 100% memory usage) and rest of space for `/home` will be ideal. Also note that all personal files goes to `/home` by default, `/home` likely to grow over time.

Comment: thnx for the ans. Jamess. For a 12gb partition, if i give 6gb to root, 2gb to swap(dont expext 100% memory usage) and 4gb to home will it be ok or you suggest a better scheme. Also will all sw that i install will go to root?

Comment: All software you install will go to the / partition (root partition).  Your home directory and personal user confgs will be in the /home partition.  Swap won't hold any data, but acts as "backup RAM" in a sense, acting as RAM when your physical RAM is fully used.

Comment: so for a 12gb space will this be right. 6gb root + 2gb swap + 4gb home

Comment: I know many who chose not set up a swap partition and if needed at a later point, you can setup swap as a file. That will further increase /home partition. It has its risks, but advantage is that you will get more space for /home, since most of  common application 4 GB RAM is enough and will not page ever (unless something  terribly goes wrong!).